# Converting .fbx to .XBL

Tags: xna, fbx, xbl

Attempting to convert a 3D object to a ".xbl" to upload to an external application however having no joy with either Autodesks old FBX Converter or my own research...

Have tried Autodesk FBX Converter 2013, Attempted to install XNA studio on win 10, also attempted importing .fbx to MONOGAME and exporting that way...

None.

One .XBL file containing a 3D Model.

Comment: What is an `.XBL` file?

Comment: Hi, .xbl is the accepted file format for the third party software in question, as far as my research shows, it's the output type from Microsofts XNA studio...